# How to get Chrome's active_tab's url by calling Python's app script?

Tags: python, py-appscript

I want to get Google Chrome's active tab's url.

In Safari,

```
url = appscript.app('Safari').windows.first.current_tab.URL()
```

Above code works, but

```
    url = appscript.app('Google Chrome').windows.first.current_tab.URL()
```

it doesn't work

Do you have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source Url --> http://reganmian.net/wiki/appscript

```
url = appscript.app("Google Chrome").windows[1].get.tabs[dt.windows[1].get.active_tab_index.get].get.URL.get
```